# Cannot reach localhost webpage Gerrit

Tags: linux, server, webserver, gerrit

Good evening folks,

I'm trying to install gerrit Code Review on my linux home server (Ubuntu Server 20.04).
Below the part of installation output that gives me problem:

```
Reindexing projects:    100% (2/2) with: reindex --site-path dev/gerrit --threads 1 --index 
project
Reindexed 2 documents in projects index in 0.1s (38.5/s)
Executing /home/gerrit/dev/gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK
Waiting for server on mylab:8080 ... OK
Opening http://mylab:8080/#/admin/projects/ ...FAILED
Open Gerrit with a JavaScript capable browser:
http://mylab:8080/#/admin/projects/
```

I am quite sure that I can not reach the local address from a browser due to that problem, but I can't find infos on the root cause of it.

Do you guys have any hint on how can I solve this issue?

thanks!

Comment: How are you installing it? Which version of Gerrit? Can you telnet to it (`telnet localhost 8080`) from the box where you are installing Gerrit?

Comment: @barbasa gerrit 3.1.3, with java sdk 1.8 on ubuntu server 20.04. 
I'm installing it following this: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install.html
I will try with telnet once I'll be back home.

Comment: you can use **bash Gerrit-Site/bin/gerrit.sh run ** to see what will stuck.